# What happens to the potential of electron?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, voltage

When we let the electron move freely in an electric field, the electric potential of electron must decrease but the electron moves opposite to the field so do we say that it's electric potential is increasing? Also what happens to its electric potential energy?

Comment: To be clear, by "potential" here, do you mean the [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) $V_E(\mathbf{x})$ or the electron potential energy $-eV_E(\mathbf{x})$?

Comment: Electric potential not electric  potential energy

Comment: Do we say the electric potential decreases or do we say the electron's potential energy decreases?

Comment: Electric potential decreases

Comment: Do you have a reference to cite for that?

Comment: By the formula E=-dV/dr we can say that potential decreases in the direction of field

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356893/

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I think the equation is based on the change in potential of a positive charge, not negative charge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we let the electron move freely in an electric field, the
>   electric potential of electron must decrease but the electron moves
>   opposite to the field so do we say that it's electric potential is
>   increasing?

When the electron moves freely in an electric field, the electric potential of the electron increases, not decreases, and its electrical potential energy decreases. This is because high and low electric potential is defined by the convention that the direction of an electric field is the direction of the force that a *positive charge* would experience if placed in the field.

Based on this convention, a positive test charge placed in a field generated by another fixed positive charge will move in the direction of the field generated by the fixed charge, i.e., away from the fixed positive charge losing both electrical potential and electrical potential energy. On the other hand, if an external force moves the positive test charge against the direction of the field, i.e., towards the fixed positive charge, the electrical potential and potential energy of the positive test charge increases. So the location of the fixed positive charge is by definition high potential.

Now, if an electron is placed in the field, the field will move the electron in a direction opposite the field moving it toward the fixed positive charge. Since the location of the fixed positive charge is defined as high potential based on convention, the electron is considered to gain potential. On the other hand, the electron clearly loses electrical potential energy.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do you mean by negative region and positive region?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta  I was thinking in terms of the electric field that exists between positive and negative charges, such as the uniform electric field in a capacitor. But I can see now that example is too restrictive  a case, so I will revise my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, now i get what you mean in the answer

Comment: @AbhinavGupta Sorry for the confusion.  I thought I saw you "accept" the answer, but now I don't see that. I must have been mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Potential is a property of the field not of any particle. As gravitation potential is of the gravitational field not of the object being pulled by it.
So this phrase " electric potential of electron" needs a reconsideration.

Comment: The potential energy of the electron is a property of the electron. We can certainly associate a potential with the field by defining it as the energy of a unit charge, but this does not mean the potential is solely a property of the field.

Answer (score 0):

The electric potential of the electron can only mean its Coulomb potetial. It does not change unless it moves at relativistic speed. As to the electric potential energy, it is converted into kinetic energy hence it decreases, while the electron is accelerated in the direction of higher external potential.